# Nova barra de navegação e a visualização Página Toda

Tags: bug

Ao utilizar o snippet para códigos HTML/CSS/JavaScript existe a opção "Página toda", para visualizar o resultado expandido.

```html
<div>Um exemplo de conteúdo</div>
```

Porém, a nova barra de navegação parece ser fixada no topo da página e sobrepõem o conteúdo, prejudicando a visualização do mesmo. Não lembro se era assim na barra antiga, acredito que não, pois nunca me chamou a atenção para isso, mas acontece nesta nova.

Esse é o comportamento esperado ou não foi percebido isso anteriormente? Acredito que inserir um espaçamento equivalente à altura da barra de navegação ao topo da visualização já resolveria o problema.

Comment: Nice, eu ia reportar isso agora mesmo. +1

Comment: O que eu falei aí em cima.

Comment: Relacionada no [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349740/4190610)

Comment: Se você clicar em "Expandir trecho de código" **antes** de clicar em "Executar", o bug não aparece.

Answer (score 4):

Só pra constar, creio que o "modais" do site também tenham sido afetados:

[image: modal]

Comment: Não seria melhor isso estar no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: @jbueno no Meta é meio comum :/

Answer (score 2):

Apenas para conhecimento, você pode desabilitar esse comportamento (barra fixa).

Para isso, basta ir nas [preferências do seu usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences) e habilitar a opção **Disable stickiness**. Fazendo isso, a barra não fica mais fixa no topo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porém, mesmo fazendo isso a barra fica sobre o snippet!**

Answer (score 1):

Se bem me lembro, isso não ocorria até uns dias atrás.

De qualquer maneira, isso é porque o `z-index` da *navbar* tá com valor **1050** e o `z-index` dos *snippets* tá com **1030**.

Talvez a galerinha dos *plugins* faça um pra solucionar isto por enquanto ***=)***

Comment: Tenho o componente no meu Chrone, [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha), do qual posso editar e salvar alterações de `CSS` em páginas, e sua solução resolve o problema. :D