# Fechar código em tela cheia

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Olá!

Vi que resolveram o [problema da barra de menu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6048/nova-barra-de-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-a-visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p%C3%A1gina-toda) que ficava em cima do código quando se colocava em tela cheia, porém agora há um outro problema: Não existe a possibilidade de fechar o código.

Quando entro no código em tela cheia, a única forma de voltar seria voltando a página (Nesse caso volto para a página anterior à da pergunta) ou dando refresh na página (O que é plausível, mas não o ideal).

Por exemplo: Veja o código abaixo, clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd> e depois <kbd>Página Toda</kbd> e verão que não será possível fechar.

```html
<p>Conteúdo Exemplo</p>
```

Comment: Não tem um "voltar para a publicação" ao lado do botão de executar?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não quando você roda o código e depois bota em tela cheia.

Comment: Reparei que é um erro que também existe na versão americana.

Comment: Descobri que é um problema de Z-Index novamente. `.snippet-code .popin { z-index: 999999; }`. Isso resolve.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não é o mesmo problema, pois esse já foi resolvido. O problema é que agora que retiraram o menu de cima, ainda permanece esse de não poder fechar.

Comment: @LeonFreire como eu disse, a outra pergunta não foi marcada com a meta-tag [meta-tag:status-pronto] como resolvido e o problema ocorre em um modo de chamar o "tela cheia", existem 2 modos (é a SO tem dessas gambiarras), vc deve ter acreditado que arrumaram por ter usado um dos modos, o que não ocorre o bug ;)

Comment: O problema é completamente diferente do anterior.

Comment: @LINQ **ok**, depois da edição deu pra entender um pouco melhor, eu comentei antes dela. Voto removido, de qualquer forma acho que era totalmente possível manter na outra pergunta. Já que nem tudo tinha sido resolvido, como os *[modais de "fechar pergunta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6061/3635)*

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Poderia até manter na outra pergunta, mas ela não é minha e nem achei ela quando pesquisei por essas palavras chaves. Então eu teria que primeiro ter achado, e depois? Acha que um comentário lá bastaria? (pergunta sincera, não é sarcasmo. Hahaha...)

Comment: @LeonFreire eu sempre me baseio pelas meta-tags status: [meta-tag:status-pronto], [meta-tag:status-intencional], [meta-tag:status-recusado], [meta-tag:status-nãorepro], [meta-tag:status-intencional], [meta-tag:status-revisão], [meta-tag:status-futuro] e [meta-tag:status-aceito], se não tem um [meta-tag:status-pronto] é por que não foi confirmado a resolução (pelo menos para a comunidade SOpt), se não foi confirmado pode editar a pergunta, ou responder adicionando mais detalhes, claro que isso ***é opinião minha***, eu sou do que sempre prefere centrar os problemas de mesma origem.

Comment: @LeonFreire não enxergo como sarcasmo e se comentei e votei como dup meu pensamento foi todo voltado para *"organizar o Meta e centralizar os problemas de mesma origem"*, eu noto que as vezes comento algo que pode ser de minha opinião ou não e mesmo com minha boa intenção algumas pessoas enxergam como um ataque pessoal, realmente eu gostaria muito que as pessoas (não estou falando de ti exatamente) presumissem mais *"boa intenção"* quando alguém comenta ao invés de se estressarem, afinal eu sou um cara que gosto de trocar ideias, mesmo que não concorde com tudo ou mesmo que eu falhe em algo ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tranquilo. Só quis explicitar porque se fosse eu a ler o que eu escrevi, me soaria como sarcasmo. Também não estou aqui para ofender ninguém.

Comment: @LeonFreire entendo obrigado, só queria dizer, mesmo que pareça sarcasmo algo que eu ler eu tento presumir *boa intenção* ;)

Comment: cross post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350699/460775

Comment: @EMBarbosa Cheguei a ver. Mas me desculpe se minha pergunta parece rude e tals, não é minha intenção. Eu que não sei muito bem as as regras aqui do Meta, mas qual o sentido em linkar um cross-post da versão americana? Já vi acontecer outras vezes, mas nem todos aqui no SOpt sabem inglês, acho inclusive que esse é o motivo de sua existência. Senão era só linkar em todas as postagens. Haha... Agora, se tem um motivo maior aqui no Meta, eu não sei.

Comment: @LeonFreire Não sei se há alguma orientação específica que motive outros a fazerem isso. Não posso falar pelos outros posts que eu não fiz, mas particularmente tenho vários motivos. Um deles é que o sistema que roda o SOpt é o mesmo que roda vários outros sites da rede SE. Provavelmente quem fará a correção em um site seria a mesma que faria em outro. Ajuda saber que é um bug já relatado. Mas de forma alguma estou desincentivando as postagens aqui.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Entendi. Foi uma pergunta mais de curiosidade mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: @EMBarbosa pode fazer sim no SOpt, é que o Gabe, que é da Staff da Stack Overflow esta de férias, quando ele voltar vai ficar tudo em dia. Só pra constar as correções feitas em outros sites nem sempre afetam este, por isso é sempre bom deixar evidente aqui também.